# import one git repo to another via TFS import

Tags: git, tfs

When you create a new repo in TFS there is an option in TFS to import from another git repo.  You can do Github, bitbucket, etc, but it does not work to import from another of my TFS repos. The reason I want to do this is because I have a project that I use as a template.

I've tried using with and without the authentication option

I expect that I should be able to clone directly.  I am on TFS on Prem version 2017.3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error too, I don't know if it's a bug or expected behavior.

As a workaround, you can manually import the repo:

Clone the source repo to a temporary folder on your computer using the bare option, as shown in the following command line example, and then navigate to the repo's folder. Note that when cloning using the bare option, the folder name includes the .git suffix. In this example, https://github.com/contoso/old-contoso-repo.git is the source repo to be manually imported.

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/contoso/old-contoso-repo.git
cd old-contoso-repo.git
```

Create a target repo using TFS 2017 RTM, and make a note of the clone URL. In this example, https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo is the URL for the new target repo.

Run the following command to copy the source repo to the target repo.

```
git push --mirror https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo
```

If the source repository has LFS objects then fetch them, and copy them from the source repo to the target repo.

```
git lfs fetch origin --all
git lfs push --all https://dev.azure.com/contoso-ltd/MyFirstProject/_git/new-contoso-repo
```

Delete the temporary folder by running the following commands.

```
cd ..
rm -rf old-contoso-repo.git
```

Comment: Thanks, that is basically what we have resorted to doing.  Well at least it's not just us.